# Initiate photo tagging via URL

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, tagging, photos

Is it possible to redirect the user to a photo URL on Facebook and automatically enable tagging?
My application uploads the photo on the user's albums and then redirects him to the photo on Facebook. Is it possible to enable tagging mode automatically?

Comment: What do you mean be “enable tagging mode”?

Comment: When the user is viewing a photo he can click on the Tag Photo button and start tagging (that's what I mean by 'tagging mode' - if its possible to start tagging without having the user to click first)

Comment: Nope, you can’t activate such functionality on the platform by just linking to it. But you now you can set tags for a photo right from your app, right? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags Maybe in combination with a friend selector that could work for you …

Comment: I'm aware that I can tag photos but i'm trying to avoid reimplementing the functionality that facebook already has, which includes face detection and the ui for tagging..

Comment: Ah OK, I didn’t think of face detection, because I have disabled that. But I’m afraid your users will have to make the click to activate the tagging mode themselves ones they arrive on the FB page of the photo.